# Liferay portlets on Grails, strengths + weaknesses?

Tags: grails, liferay, jsr168

I'm interested in the possibility of developing **Liferay** portlets on Grails, using the [Grails Portlets plugin](http://grails.org/Portlets+Plugin). I reckon introducing a portlet framework (such as the Spring Portlet API) will make development faster and more comfortable, so being able to further add Groovy and Grails conventions to the mix sounds almost too good to be true.

I guess this combo is relatively new, since this far I've found no experiences on how well this works in practice, or of its potential pitfalls.

Any experiences, suggestions or warnings? I would greatly appreciate them.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the plugin is very new so you might have to get involved by suggesting improvements/logging JIRAs.

But I think the nice Grails features would make it worth the while. Both Kenji and I read the mailing list so you should get an answer to any questions you have.

I've never used it to create a real application (only test apps while developing the original plugin code which Kenji has since improved).